# Permission issues in docker + laravel

Tags: php, docker, laravel

I've been having this problem for a week and I don't know how to solve it. I started a small laravel project with Docker and Docker's mysql doesn't work at all. It keeps crashing by itself, when running **docker logs my-container** I get these errors: *Cannot change permissions of the file 'private_key.pem.temp' (OS errno 1 - Operation not permitted)*

My settings:
.env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql 
DB_HOST=mysql 
DB_PORT=3306 
DB_DATABASE=laravel_ead
DB_USERNAME=sail 
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

Docker-compose.yml:

```
mysql:
          image: mysql:8.0
          restart: unless-stopped
          environment:
              MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
              MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
              MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
              MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
          command: ["--disable-partition-engine-check"]
          volumes:
              - ./.docker/mysql/dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
                - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
          ports:
              - 3388:3306
          networks:
              - laravel-eti
```

I've already tried changing the ports, I've already tried changing the DB_HOST to 127.0.0.1 for localhost, I've already tried clearing the cache, I've already installed and tried to use sail, I've already tried deleting the entire project and starting over, I've already uninstalled and reinstalled docker and nothing. I'm using windows(wsl2). Before I got this error every time I ran php artisan migrate - error: **SQLSTATE[HY000] [1130] Host '172.20.0.6' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server.**  If you find it necessary, here is the project: https://github.com/mrnightone/laravel-docker.git

Comment: Check that the user is allowed to log in? The error message explains things fairly well, in plain English.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, could you give me a tip on how to do this?